# How to name newly joined table

Tags: join

This is a very basic question. I joined two tables and I need to manipulate a column within the new set(?). However I don't know what the name of the newly joined table is or how to access it. I would like it to come up in the **describe** command so I can work with it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Describe will only work on a "real" table, a JOIN creates more a virtual set combining the data from two or more other tables. Although it is returned in one sec, the data still distinctily belongs to one table or another, and can't describe it because it's not an actual table.

Comment: If you do want a join to be more like a table, you should look into "views"

Comment: What database is this? SQL, MySQL, other?

Comment: Its in mysql database, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You can give them an alias:

SELECT
t1.name,
t2.adress

FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I think I need to be more clear. I can join the tables successfully. Now that the tables are joined how do I work with the newly joined table. I'm thinking giving it a name is a start.

Comment: I think you need to give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: I will try my best.mysql> SELECT orders.order_id, orders.order_date, order_item_subtotal From  orders JOIN order_items on (orders.order_id = order_items.order_item_order_id)                                                                                        This code worked fine but now I don't know how to access my "joinedtable" i only know how to look at the output that comes up as soon as I execute the command. Although I have joined the table there is more work I have to do to the "joined table" and I don't know how to access it.